# how to separate and display 2nd select data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select option and a button validate, the 1st fill by cities, countries and coleurs, and the 2nd fill by names, numbers and salaries, I want when I click on button validate to display the data of 2nd select as above:
name:
registration number :
salary :
but in my case it displays the 1st select data.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {

    let selectOption = $('.form-control').val();
    let optionSplits = selectOption.split('-');

    let name1 = optionSplits[0];
    let matricule1 = optionSplits[1];
    let salary1 = optionSplits[2];

    $('#nam').text(name1);
    $('#mat').text(matricule1);
    $('#sal').text(salary1);

    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="city1-country1-color1">city1 country1 color1</option>
      <option value="city2-country2-color2">city2 country2 color2</option>
      <option value="city3-country3-color3">city3 country3 color3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="name1-22-6000">name1 22 6000</option>
      <option value="name2-24-8000">name2 24 8000</option>
      <option value="name3-27-5000">name3 27 5000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--form 2-->
<div id="form2">
  <h4>name : <span id="nam"></span></h4>
  <h4>matricule : <span id="mat"></span></h4>
  <h4>salary : <span id="sal"></span></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used selector `.form-control` that match both of your select. You should add id to your 2nd select and use that id to get value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {

    let selectOption = $('#second_select').val();
    let optionSplits = selectOption.split('-');

    let name1 = optionSplits[0];
    let matricule1 = optionSplits[1];
    let salary1 = optionSplits[2];

    $('#nam').text(name1);
    $('#mat').text(matricule1);
    $('#sal').text(salary1);

    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form1">
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="city1-country1-color1">city1 country1 color1</option>
      <option value="city2-country2-color2">city2 country2 color2</option>
      <option value="city3-country3-color3">city3 country3 color3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="second_select">
      <option value="name1-22-6000">name1 22 6000</option>
      <option value="name2-24-8000">name2 24 8000</option>
      <option value="name3-27-5000">name3 27 5000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--form 2-->
<div id="form2">
  <h4>name : <span id="nam"></span></h4>
  <h4>matricule : <span id="mat"></span></h4>
  <h4>salary : <span id="sal"></span></h4>
</div>
```